# How count number of values before an specify hour in timedate Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, count

I work with this kind of data, I build my pandas and use group_by to round my value to 15m...
One thing never work, how count number of value falling under 11h00? Here a sample of my data

```
index      DATEHEUREMAX
12:07      2019-06-03  12:07:28
10:04      2019-06-04  10:04:25
11:14      2019-06-09  11:14:25
```

I can't figure out how specify only the hour...

Comment: What is your desired output for that sample data? Also the `dtypes`?

Comment: in this exemple  output =1, only one value fall under 11h00

Comment: `(df.index.hour == 11).sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.hour`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html)

```
(df['DATEHEUREMAX'].dt.hour < 11).sum()
#1
```

---

If you want filter your dataframe:

```
df_filtered=df[(df['DATEHEUREMAX'].dt.hour<11)]
print(df_filtered)

   index        DATEHEUREMAX
1  10:04 2019-06-04 10:04:25
```

---

Now you could also calculate the number of rows:

```
len(df)
#1
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually we do

```
df.index=pd.to_timedelta(df.index+':00')
df.loc[df.index<='11:00:00']
Out[137]: 
                  DATEHEUREMAX
index                         
10:04:00  2019-06-04  10:04:25
sum(df.index<='11:00:00')
Out[138]: 1
```